# efficiently find subset of records as well as total count

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion

I'm writing a function in ColdFusion that returns the first couple of records that match the user's input, as well as the total count of matching records in the entire database.  The function will be used to feed an autocomplete, so speed/efficiency are its top concerns.  For example, if the function receives input `"bl"`, it might return `{sampleMatches:["blue", "blade", "blunt"], totalMatches:5000}`

I attempted to do this in a single query for speed purposes, and ended up with something that looked like this:

```
select record, count(*) over ()
from table
where criteria like :criteria
and rownum <= :desiredCount
```

The problem with this solution is that `count(*) over ()` always returns the value of `:desiredCount`.  I saw a similar question to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015781/getting-a-subset-of-records-along-with-total-record-count), but my app will not have permissions to create a temp table.  So is there a way to solve my problem in one query?  Is there a better way to solve it?  Thanks!

Comment: will your "criteria" be restricted to a set of criteria that you know you can use an index for?  If user can set any crazy criteria, you'll be doing a lot of full scans

Comment: Out of curiousity, if the function is to be used for autocomplete, what is the purpose of the count?

Comment: @tbone the criteria column is already indexed

Comment: @DanBracuk the autocomplete has two use cases; looking for a set of similar records and looking for an exact record.  When looking for an exact record, the user starts with a general idea of what they want and filter it down based on the autocomplete responses.  When looking for a group of records, the user wants to know how many matches the current criteria has to see if they should keep narrowing their criteria down until they eventually select view all matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm writing this on top of my head, so you should definitely have to time this, but I believe that using following CTE

- only requires you to write the conditions once
- only returns the amount of records you specify
- has the correct total count added to each record
- and is evaluated only once

**SQL Statement**

```
WITH q AS (
  SELECT record
  FROM   table
  WHERE  criteria like :criteria
)
SELECT q1.*, q2.*
FROM   q q1
       CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT COUNT(*) FROM q
       ) q2
WHERE  rownum <= :desiredCount
```

Comment: That did it, thanks!  To get it to work I had to remove the `as` keywords, but it ran smoothly otherwise.

Comment: @Ben - you have removed the `as` keyword as it's not supported by oracle, tx, but removing the aliasses can't be right?! *(I can't test that right now)*

Comment: No, sorry that was me being dumb. You need the aliases.

Answer (score 3):

A nested subquery should return the results you want

```
select record, cnt
  from (select record, count(*) over () cnt
          from table
         where criteria like :criteria) 
 where rownum <= :desiredCount
```

This will, however, force Oracle to completely process the query in order to generate the accurate `count`.  This seems unlikely to be what you want if you're trying to do an autocomplete particularly when Oracle may decide that it would be more efficient to do a table scan on `table` if `:criteria` is just `b` since that predicate isn't selective enough.  Are you really sure that you need a completely accurate count of the number of results?  Are you sure that your table is small enough/ your system is fast enough/ your predicates are selective enough for that to be a requirement that you could realistically meet?  Would it be possible to return a less-expensive (but less-accurate) estimate of the number of rows?  Or to limit the `count` to something smaller (say, 100) and have the UI display something like "and 100+ more results"?

Comment: For this specific case I need the exact count.  But for future needs, how could I go about building an estimate?

Comment: @Josh - It depends.  You can generate a query plan, for example, and use the estimated number of rows returned.  You can use the `SAMPLE` clause and multiply by an appropriate factor.  You can create histograms that are based on the prevalence of your data and refresh them periodically (or even potentially use the histograms that the optimizer has generated).